# every time loop is finished return something C#

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

hi I Want to loop over a data and each time it's iterating return something. I know if if use return inside loop the loop will be finished is there any other way. Thanks for helping.

[some thing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfaQp.png)

reply to kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze
no it's like a list of data when user clicks post it should remove the ones which are finished from list or send a msg like remove data where id == id and i could remove it from list in angular front-end

let me show you the real code what i want

```
 foreach (var item in data)
        {
            var FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + item.CustomerName + ".pdf";
            var filePath = root + FileName;
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                // create pdf file
                var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
                doc.Open();
                doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(item.Data));
                doc.Close();
                // create pdf file ended

                // send email
                sendEmail(item.CustomerName, filePath);
                // in here i want to send back a response that the file with id item.id is created so remove it from table 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Return an array?

Comment: You can use `yield` and make it a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

Comment: You can use a froEach constructor. forEach won't return anything. It's not a for loop.

Comment: Use a loop that lets you call a function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: it sounds like you want to filter your list, then do something with it, why not just use .filter and pass around that array?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove multiply rows from table make an array of succesfuly created files

and then return this array

elements of array will be item.id

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're trying to do, but if you let the script loop in a different thread then after sendEmail() you could trigger an event which get caught by the main thread?

Or when you have a datagrid and remove the value, it gets deleted real time?